# how to initially open a table view to a selected detail view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a navigation controller linked to a tab bar controller which links to a table view controller.

I would like to have the table view open initially with the topic list. It currently opens on the detail view of the Table View Controller.

Is there a way to do this? Using Swift and Xcode.
Here's the code in the Master Controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TopicList", ofType: "plist")!
    let topicsDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)!
    topics = topicsDict["topics"]! as! [NSDictionary] as! [[String: String]]
    keys = topicsDict.allKeys as! [String]

    //let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        self.detailViewController = split.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
            let object = topics[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is. Before you show the table view, you can push the detail view controller onto the stack.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to do that when I'm opening it from the tab bar controller, nor how to specify the initial file for the view.

Comment: Well how are your views initially setup? Some code would be nice.

Comment: Here's the code in the Master Controller:

Comment: Put it in your question

Answer (score 1):

I got no responses, but I did solve the problem by adding an option for the initial view in the Master Controller code:

```
    func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            let dict = detail as! [String: String]
            let urlString = dict["url"]!

            let pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(urlString, ofType: "pdf")!)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc!)
            webView.loadRequest(request)


            let topic = dict["title"]!

            title = ""
            label.text = topic

            let bottomOffString = dict["bottom"]!
            if bottomOffString == "1" {
                buttonSwitch.enabled = false
                buttonSwitch.hidden = true
            } else {
                buttonSwitch.setTitle("Details =>", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
    } else {
        let urlString = "Quick Tips"
        let pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(urlString, ofType: "pdf")!)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        title = "Quick Tips"
        //label.text = "Quick Tips"
        buttonSwitch.enabled = false
        buttonSwitch.hidden = true
    }
}
```